# How to correctly setup a Deposit function for a bank in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a rudimentary online bank where customers can create accounts and make deposits into their accounts. This is the first time I've used Phoenix and Elixir and I'm having a lot of trouble with the deposit function. My thinking is that all a customer would need to deposit money is their account ID and the amount of money. I have therefore made a function for this in the user_controller which inputs the ID alongside the amount, however, I am getting the dreaded `no function clause matching in SpBankWeb.UserController.deposit/2` error in postman when I try to post into it... perhaps due to how I am posting to it or how my logic is structured - or perhaps both of these things.

My POST request contains this as the body `{"id" :{"amount":200.0}}` and is correctly to the route `http://localhost:4000/api/deposit` (do I need to make any changes to this?). This results in the input, alongside the no function matching error,

```
# 2
%{"id" => %{"amount" => 200.0}}
```

1. *This is the first thing that is confusing me, as my function takes in an ID and an amount, which is what is shown above - why is this not matching?*  The corresponding user function is below:

User_controller:

```
defmodule SpBankWeb.UserController do
  use SpBankWeb, :controller

  alias SpBank.Account
  alias SpBank.Account.User

  action_fallback SpBankWeb.FallbackController

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Account.list_users()
    render(conn, "index.json", users: users)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    with {:ok, %User{} = user} <- Account.create_user(user_params) do
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> put_resp_header("location", Routes.user_path(conn, :show, user))
      |> render("show.json", user: user)
    end
  end

  def deposit(conn, %{"id" => id, "amount" => amount}) do
    user = Account.get_user!(id)
    with {:ok, %User{} = user} <- Account.deposit(user, amount) do
      render(conn, "show.json", user: user)
    end
  end
```

2. Or, does the problem arise instead due to the router as below. *Why, for instance, did I need to specify the route of POST here when for the other user_controller methods these simply came with the 'resources' of /users?*

Router.ex:

```
defmodule SpBankWeb.Router do
  use SpBankWeb, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/api", SpBankWeb do
    pipe_through :api
    resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/transactions", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
    post "/deposit", UserController, :deposit
  end
```

Account.Transactions.ex:

```
defmodule SpBank.Account.Transaction do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias SpBank.Account.User

  schema "transactions" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    field :amount, :decimal

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(transaction, attrs) do
    transaction
    |> cast(attrs, [:id, :amount])
    |> assoc_constraint(:user)
    |> validate_required([:id, :amount])
  end
end
```

Account.user.ex:

```
defmodule SpBank.Account.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias SpBank.Account.Transaction
  schema "users" do
    # field :id 
    field :amount, :decimal
    field :name, :string
    has_many :transactions, Transaction 
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :amount])
    |> validate_required([:name, :amount])
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a closer look at your POST body.  It looks like you are setting the amount under the ID key.  Should these not be separate?

Comment: In the function you expect to receive `%{"id" => id, "amount" => amount}`, while in the body you sent `%{"id" => %{"amount" => 200.0}}` they obviously don’t match and I thing the latter is not correct.